# What's this kind of menu called?

Tags: navigation, menu, terminology

When you click a link, it opens another tab and puts a link to the previous one on it's top.

It solves my problem, but I can't find what it's named *(english is not my 1st language)*.

Here's an example taken from YouTube. *I'm not interested on the resizing part, as mine will be fixed size.*

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Terms that come to mind are cascaded or nested slideout sidebar menu

Comment: I would go with "Unexposed dialog menu"..  

as Material UI has classic drop down menu with this style where items are shown right away, and its called "exposed dropdown menu"

Comment: technically speaking, it's a multi level menu, only that instead of keeping inactive levels visible it completely hides them. Kind of https://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index3.html#

Comment: Yup I agree with @Devin. It's a type of a multi-level push menu.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Devin and the terminology that could be used is `Nested Multi-Level Push Menu`.

Links:
[jQuery](https://plugins.jquery.com/multilevelpushmenu/)
[HTML / CSS / JS](https://codepen.io/romswellparian/pen/aOJbOL)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to UX StackExchange. This answer is more like a comment than an answe

Answer (score 0):

It can be called Nested Menu. You can refer the example in below link

https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview